# How do I get Filterrific Javascript and Assets to run on Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filterrific

I used the code from demo and the scopes and form work by themselves. 
When I added Materialize forms, I noticed that the form and filtering doesn't anymore.

Apparently filterrific doesn't load its javascript library (I loaded Jquery for materialize, which works fine).

From my understanding

```
//= require filterrific/filterrific-jquery
```

in assets/javascript/application.js won't work (also tried).

I also get an asset error

```
Asset `filterrific/filterrific-spinner.gif` was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Declare links to your assets in `app/assets/config/manifest.js`.
```

The gem seems Rails 6 ready (says the table on github), but there is no documentation on how to make it work with Rails 6 and WebPacker.

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to app/assets/config/manifest.js

//= link filterrific/filterrific-spinner.gif